# Generate jira Cookie from user and password

Tags: python, authentication, cookies, python-requests, jira-rest-api

Hi i am new to Python automation and Jira.

i am able to login JIRA and fetch all the data i want using python code, but authentication is the problem when i am fetching data, i am using USER , PASSWORD and COOKIE and whenever i fetch data everytime i have set new cookie.

i want to generate jira Cookie from user and password, can anyone help me with this or suggest how this can be acheived. Thanks

```
import base64
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


class Client:
    def __init__(self, base_url: str, username: str, password: str, cookie: str):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.auth_token = base64.b64encode((username + ":" + password).encode('UTF-8'))
        self.cookie = cookie

    def headers(self):
        return {
            'Cookie': self.cookie,
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + str(self.auth_token.decode('UTF-8'))
        }
```

i want to avoid setting cookie in runtime variables every time i run it, please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can find a very detailed explanation here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/cookie-based-authentication/

You can also use the Jira Client python package, that handles the login for you: https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html#cookie-based-authentication